# replace the string from just before the last dot(.)

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like A/B/C/D.txt

So I want to replace the character just before the last . with the new one.
Like I would add E in last So the output should be A/B/C/E.txt

Can this is possible with only replace and concat Or Regex should help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the output is correct.

```
A/B/C/E.txt
```

```js
var filename = 'A/B/C/D.txt';
var dotIndex = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
document.write(filename.substr(0, dotIndex-1) + 'E'+filename.substr(dotIndex, filename.length-dotIndex));
```

Comment: Yes, Working like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```js
     var parts = 'A/B/C/D.txt'.split('.');
            
         if(parts.length > 1) 
         {
            parts[parts.length-2] = parts[parts.length-2].replace(/.$/,"E");
            let result  = parts.join('.');
            console.log(result);
         }
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg but result only adding new text and result is E.txt and expecting result is A/B/C/E.txt

Comment: I modified script with code  snippet

Comment: Another way with Regex: 'A/B/C/D.txt'.replace(/D\.(?=[^.])/, "E.");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let name = "A/B/C/D.txt"
let res = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")) + "E." + name.substr(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks Sourabh, But in your code response like A/B/C/D.Etxt instead of A/B/C/E.txt

Comment: @Dharam1986 Ohh sorry just missed it. Edited this please check now.

Comment: Still output like A/B/C/D.E.txt

Comment: @Dharam1986 try now :)

Comment: Now it is returning A/B/C/DE.txt